# Python, all combinations of arrays array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need help with my code. I am doing small code for generating synthetic seismic accelerations. And I am little stuck due to code/my inefficiency. I have matrix **aaa**, but de facto it is vector of vectors. Each row correspond to particular eigenvalue. And in row is time history. In my example I have 4 eigenvalues = 4 rows, and time divided to 7 parts. Due to **aaa.shape= (4L, 7L)**

```
aaa=array([
[1.90e-17,  -1.58e-02,   8.64e-03,   2.35e-02,   8.64e-03,  -1.58e-02,  -7.07e-18],
[-1.70e-05,  -9.20e-03,   6.13e-02,  -2.53e-08,  -6.13e-02,   9.20e-03,   1.70e-05],
[-1.52e-16,  -4.13e-02,  -5.48e-02,   1.23e-01,  -5.48e-02,  -4.13e-02,   7.26e-17],
[-2.05e-07,  -1.37e-01,   9.93e-02,  -1.22e-12,  -9.93e-02,   1.37e-01,   2.05e-07]])
```

I have working code (inefficient), it is very simple:

```
for i in xrange(0,len(aaa)):
    for j in xrange(0,len(aaa)):
        fiMN2[j,i]=np.dot(aaa[i],aaa[j])`

    fiMN2
    array([[  4.8234e-03,  -4.3786e-09,   1.3096e-02,  -7.2303e-15],
           [ -4.3786e-09,   3.0817e-02,  -1.4847e-08,   5.8952e-02],
           [  1.3096e-02,  -1.4847e-08,   9.8940e-02,  -9.9190e-13],
           [ -7.2303e-15,   5.8952e-02,  -9.9190e-13,   2.3102e-01]])
```

But I would like to work with 1000s eigenvalues and circa 10000 timesteps, and for these is my code useless due to for loops. Please, could you help me with something more elegant? I am trying to implement `numpy.outer`, `numpy.meshgrid` but without success. I little rounded values of **aaa** and **fiMN2** because it wouldn't fit into window. Thanks, BR, Igor

Comment: Try : `aaa.dot(aaa.T)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, when I see answer I understand. But again - thanks, you save a lot of my time. And sorry for duplicate question :/ I really google this problem few hours, but my programming skills.. BR, Igor